# Virtuemart - how to create product detail url

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I am developing a custom search module/component. I get the list of products of Virtuemart but I don't know how to build the URL of each product, because my product belongs to many categories.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 3.X this works for me

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id='.$X);
```

Where `$X` is your product ID. This will give you the "final" (possibly pretty) URL.
Note that this ***returns*** the URL...

Common mistake is requesting the wrong view (product, productdetail (no *"s"*
 at the end), ...), the view you want really is *exactly* "productdetails".

Answer (score 0):

i'm working with Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2 (not sure if the same as yours) and the url is working without category:

normal url: `<your domain>index.php/virtuemart/category_1/<product_alias>-detail`
url withowt category: `<your domain>index.php/virtuemart/<product_alias>-detail`

for me both are working